# Leverage CDS Connector from Commercial Azure Tenant Logic App to connect to GCC Power Platform Environment

Tags: azure-logic-apps, common-data-service, power-platform, dataverse

Is it possible to use the [Common Data Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/commondataservice/) connector from an Azure Logic App running in a commercial Azure Tenant to connect to a GCC (government) Power Platform/Dataverse instance? I've not found any specific documentation saying it's not allowed, but after authenticating with the connector no environments are listed even though I'm a sys admin. Unfortunately, I don't have access to a GCC Azure tenant with rights to try a similar test.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raised a support ticket with MSFT and they said currently the CDS connector used from an Azure Logic App doesn't support connecting to GCC Dataverse. No timeline for when this will be supported.